# Android Convert Json into ArrayList Multilevel Expandable Listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

I'm new in Android Programming. I have a class with data from json on Multilevel ExpandableListview. I want to show the DivisionName value into first row(parent) of list, SubDivisionName value into second row(child) and all of Vehicle values into third row(grandchild). So, this is the json data

```
[
{
    "DivisionID": "2c0e9dc1-a6a7",
    "DivisionName": "Tyuio",
    "SubDivision": [
        {
            "SubDivisionID": "70c3ac53-eec6",
            "SubDivisionName": "FM2222",
            "Vehicle": [
                {
                    "Nopol": "00571564",
                    "LastUpdate": "Oct 10 2010 10:10AM",
                    "LastSpeed": 0,
                    "LastLon": 106.82176
                    "Location": "KNOWHERE"
                },
                {
                    "Nopol": "352848020936627",
                    "LastUpdate": "Oct 10 2010 10:10AM",
                    "LastSpeed": 0,
                    "LastLon": 10124.228
                    "Location": "KNOWHERE2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I'm try to populate it into ArrayList. I've been able to parse a json data. I want to through json to list. This is the Multilevel expandableListview code

```
private static final String DIV_NAME= "DivisionName";
private static final String SUBDIV_NAME = "SubDivisionName";
private static final String TAG_NOPOL = "Nopol";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

// third row (subchild-list)
    ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
    mItemListArray.add(new ItemList(TAG_NOPOL, TAG_LOCATION,TAG_LONG));

// second row (child-list)
    pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
    pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory(SUBDIV_NAME, mItemListArray));    

// first row (parent-list)
    pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();
    pProductArrayList.add(new Product(DIV_NAME, pSubItemArrayList));
```

I want to show tyuio into first row of list(parent), FM222 into second row of list(child), and all of vehicle values into third row(grandchild). These JSON data is dynamic. Is there a way to convert json into this arrayList? i have seen many tutorials but those wasn't helpful for me. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

i refers to [this](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/07/android-multilevel-expandable-listview.html) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the response to a list.

I would recommend to do the following:

Create a response class:

```
public class DivisionResponse {

    @SerializedName("DivisionID")
    public String divisionId;

    @SerializedName("DivisionName")
    public String divisionName;

    @SerializedName("DivisionName")
    public List< SubDivision> subdivision;

    public class Subdivision{

           @SerializedName("SubDivisionId")
           public String SubDivisionId;

           @SerializedName("SubDivisionName")
           public String SubDivisionName;

           @SerializedName("Vehicle")
           public List<Vehicle> SubDivisionName;

           public class Vehicle{


                @SerializedName("Nopol")
                public String nopol;

                @SerializedName("LastUpdate")
                public String LastUpdate;

                @SerializedName("LastSpeed")
                public String LastSpeed;


                @SerializedName("LastLon")
                public String LastLon;


                @SerializedName("Location")
                public String Location;
           }
    }
}
```

Then you would use gson to cast the response to this class.
When you receive that object or response convert it to text.

```
List<DivisionResponse> response = gson.fromJson(theonjecttext, new TypeToken<List<DivisionResponse>>() {}.getType());
```

that should create a list with all the data you need.

Make sure gson is added to the dependencies of gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

This code is specific to your response provided.

The response class could be independent classes instead of inner classes. Its up to you.

```
<dependencies>
    <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm android project Eclipse user. i am new in gson. is it works if i use maven project and gson 2.3?

Comment: Yea it should. See my updated answer. You should convert to Android Studio. You will be much more productive :)